# How to calculate material depth at which penetrating radiation direction becomes randomized?

Tags: radiation, scattering

Consider a very light particle impinging on a material composed of atoms which are effectively infinitely heavy (e.g., because they are bound together and stiff).  If the scattering with nuclei is fully elastic (and electron scattering can be neglected), then the incident particle energy remains the same after each collisions.  If the differential cross-section is constant (aka hard-sphere scattering, aka s-wave scattering) then the direction of the incident particle is randomized after a single collision.  However, if the cross-section is weighted preferentially toward the forward direction, as it is with a Yukawa potential, then there will be many collisions before the direction randomizes.

**How does one calculate the depth at which the direction randomizes?**  I am tempted to treat the scattering events as small steps as part of a random walk on the unit sphere, so that the incident direction disperses like the square root of the penetration depth. When the dispersion covers most of the unit sphere, the direction is randomized.  (However, this is complicated by the fact that the distribution of scattering angles for a Yukawa cross-section does not have a finite variance in the small angle limit.)

References and search keywords greatly appreciated.

Note that this is different than the penetration depth, Bragg peak, etc., at least conceptually.  In the above case, dE/dx is zero.

Comment: You might consider building a computational model and trying to to compute a [Lyapunov exponent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_exponent) on the photon direction.

Comment: This and much harder problems have long ago been solved by radiation transport codes. Are you trying to understand how these codes work or are you trying to derive a theoretical model?

Comment: Theory of course. Using numerical codes for this would be like using an N body simulation for a single orbit.